# No interaction for three-way ANOVA what is next?

Tags: anova, interpretation

I ran a three-way ANOVA to find effect of insecticide (2 levels), species (2 levels) and location (2 levels) on body condition of turtles. I did not find any three-way interaction. However, I found an interaction between insecticide and species! I am not familiar with three-way ANOVA and I dont know how should I interpret my results and plot my data!! should I run a two-way ANOVA and focus on main effects?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to work with the model as is. Plot your data! What does it say? What about post-hoc tests? Keep going!

Comment: So, you are saying I should run a Two-way? sorry I did not get it

Comment: Probably running a three way with that one significant two-way interaction would work. One could wonder whether some simple transformation of the response variable would eliminate the interaction, but we can't say much about that without the actual data.

Comment: Ok, so should I report two-way interaction between insecticide and species. and also report F value for each factor from the same table? or run two-way ANOVA and conclude on that?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ok, so should I report two-way interaction between insecticide and species. and also report F value for each factor from the same table? or run two-way ANOVA and conclude on that?

Comment: @jebyrnes So, you are saying I should run a Two-way? sorry I did not get it

Comment: @Non : Yes. How big is your dataset?

Comment: Michael Hardy Sorry again! should I report F value from which table?? I have 80 samples. (2X2X2 design). I found  another way using syntax to compute main effects but I am not sure about that!! So please correct me if I am wrong! I should report F value for insecticide * species interaction! then report F value for each main effect! and finally plot my data based on one of the factors like insecticide?

Comment: I agree with @jebyrnes - plot your data, use the entire 3-way ANOVA table and post-hoc tests. A picture paints a thousand words so plot your data! You might be able to get more useful answers by posting the ANOVA table in your question, as well as any graphs you have.

Comment: Yup, if this is a confirmatory, not exploratory, analysis, use your model for your posthocs. Plot plot plot.  If this is exploratory, meh, you can refit, but, your milage may vary. Depends on how and why you are asking your question.